# If a text box contains text then display a second text box under it else hide second text box

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have multiple text boxes under each other. I would like them all to be hidden except the first one. If the first box has text in it then the second box should display. If the second box has text in it then the third box will display.

Comment: Set their `.visible` property based on the value of the previous box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a text box only if the text box above it has a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979105/display-a-text-box-only-if-the-text-box-above-it-has-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *AfterUpdate* event of the textbox, here for the first:

```
Me!TextBox2.Visible = Not IsNull(Me!TextBox1.Value)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your textboxes are named `txtBox1` to `txtBox6` you can place this procedure in the `AfterUpdate` event of each of them.

The procedure also sets the value of invisible textboxes to `Null`. If you don't want that, just comment the regarding line of code.

```
Private Sub SetTextBoxes(ByVal startWithTextBoxNr As Long)
    Const TEXTBOX_COUNT As Long = 6
    Const COMMON_NAME As String = "txtBox"

    Dim index As Long
    For index = startWithTextBoxNr + 1 To TEXTBOX_COUNT
        With Me(COMMON_NAME & index)
            .Visible = Not IsNull(Me(COMMON_NAME & index - 1).Value)
            If Not .Visible Then .Value = Null
        End With
    Next index
End Sub
```

The event handlers would look like this:

```
Private Sub txtBox1_AfterUpdate()
    SetTextBoxes 1
End Sub

Private Sub txtBox2_AfterUpdate()
    SetTextBoxes 2
End Sub

Private Sub txtBox3_AfterUpdate()
    SetTextBoxes 3
End Sub

Private Sub txtBox4_AfterUpdate()
    SetTextBoxes 4
End Sub

Private Sub txtBox5_AfterUpdate()
    SetTextBoxes 5
End Sub
```

Additionally you could add `SetTextBoxes` to the `Load` event of the form to initialize the controls once for the first textbox:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    SetTextBoxes 1
End Sub
```